# getting out of memory error for higher values

Tags: java

Problem statement is:
The Ruler of HackerLand believes that every citizen of the country should have access to a library. Unfortunately, HackerLand was hit by a tornado that destroyed all of its libraries and obstructed its roads! As you are the greatest programmer of HackerLand, the ruler wants your help to repair the roads and build some new libraries efficiently.

HackerLand has n cities numbered from 1 to n. The cities are connected by m  bidirectional roads. A citizen has access to a library if:

Their city contains a library.
They can travel by road from their city to a city containing a library.
The cost of repairing any road is y dollars, and the cost to build a library in any city is x dollars.

You are given q queries, where each query consists of a map of HackerLand and value of x and y.

For each query, find the minimum cost of making libraries accessible to all the citizens and print it on a new line.

getting out of memory error java heap size whenever i enter larger values like 90k or more for n,m for smaller values code works fine!!!!
the question is related to graph theory and am is adjacency matrix
the first two lines of input are :
10
78148 11354 90581 83503 
      package solution22;

```
  import java.io.*;
  import java.util.*;
  import java.text.*;
  import java.math.*;
  import java.util.regex.*;

   public class Solution22 
  {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int q = in.nextInt();
    for(int a0 = 0; a0 < q; a0++)
    {
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int m = in.nextInt();
        long x = in.nextLong();
        long y = in.nextLong();
        int[][] am=new int [n+1][n+1];
        long total=0; 
        for(int a1 = 0; a1 < m; a1++)
        {
            int city_1 = in.nextInt();
            int city_2 = in.nextInt();
            am[city_1][city_2]=am[city_2][city_1]=1;
        }
        if(x<y)
        {
            total=n*x;
        }
        else
        {
            long[] tc=new long[n+1];
            boolean[] cl=new boolean[n+1];
            tc[1]=x;
            cl[1]=true;
            for(int i=2;i<=n;i++)
            {
                for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
                {
                    if(am[i][j]==1&&cl[j])
                    {
                        tc[i]=y;
                        cl[i]=true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(!cl[i])
                {
                    tc[i]=x;
                    cl[i]=true;
                }
            }
            for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
            {
                total+=tc[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(total);
    }
}
  }
```

The code works fine for smaller values of n m x y

Comment: two options- increase your JVM memory or optimize your code :)

Comment: With variable names like `tc`, `cl`, `n`, `m`, `x`, `y`, how do you expect people to approach your code? People aren't gonna bother reverse engineering this if it requires them to look variables up in a glossary every time they read them

Comment: agree. Put some proper names to your variable, that will improve the code readability

Comment: I agree with the comments above, the code is not really nice to go through. When i run the program myself i get the error on this line: `int[][] am=new int [n+1][n+1];`. When i looked at what the line did i saw the problem which caused the memory error. When your n is `78148`, java tries to make this array `int[78149][78149]`. Meaning that java tries to allocate `(78149^2)*32 bytes` (Amount of integers * java integer size). This is equal to aprox. 22.75 GB. Now this may be a problem :P

Comment: Thanks @ChrisWitteveen